# Wrong charset with JSON data in Node.js project

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

How can I fix the following problem?

If I use this code on app.js it renders the page with no problem:

```
app.get('/layout', function(req, res){    
res.render('empreendimentolayout', {"titulo": "Página Layout"})
})
```

.ejs file is like this:

```
<head>
<title><%=titulo%></title>
</head>
```

But if I do this on app.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.get('/layout', routes.layout);
```

And inside layout.js:

```
exports.layout = function(req, res){
res.render('empreendimentolayout', {"titulo": "Página Layout"})
})
```

Then rendering will be like:
P�gina Layout

It happens in all JSON data I send. If it is coming directly from app.js it works well, but if it is coming from another .js file it comes with the wrong charset.

Comment: It looks as if the encoding of the file `app.js:` differs from the file `layout.js` encoding. Check it.

Comment: The problem was on Webstorm. New .js files were created with ISO 8859-1 encoding. I changed it and it works now!